# Aggregating Gradle project-report reports for subprojects

Tags: gradle, project, reporting

As per title, is there a way to have aggregated project reports for all the subprojects? In my build.gradle I have something like:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'project-report'
  // ... more stuff
}
```

but then I end up with one report per subproject. It would be nice to have all the reports in one place but I couldn't figure out how. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the plugin in the root project and simply set the projects property of the project-report plugin to subprojects? [Plugin Doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/project_reports_plugin.html)

Comment: I tried `projectReport.projects = subprojects` with no luck. I get a warning that says `Deprecated dynamic property: "projects" on "task ':projectReport'", value: ...`. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: It looks like support for changing the projects is not there yet.  Looking at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/diagnostics/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/ProjectReportsPluginConvention.groovy it looks like project is a property, and getProjects just wraps that project in a set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just noticed in the [documentation for the `htmlDependencyReport` task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.reporting.dependencies.HtmlDependencyReportTask.html) that you can do this now:

```
apply plugin: 'project-report'

htmlDependencyReport {
    projects = project.allprojects
}
```

Note that the plugin is being applied to the root project here, not in a `subprojects` configuration block as shown in the question.

I don't know which version of Gradle added this feature, but I can confirm it works in Gradle 2.0. According to the current docs (Gradle 2.2.1, January 2015) this feature is still incubating.

Comment: Did you test it? I am not using Gradle anymore but if you can confirm it works I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using this form in my build and it works nicely.